# Как передать NULL через переменную в sql запрос?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть переменная:

```
$param = NULL;
```

Делаю такой запрос:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `products` (`name`) VALUES ('$param')");
```

В итоге запрос получается таким:

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`name`) VALUES ('')
```

А если переменную указать так:

```
$param = 'NULL';
```

Тогда запрос будет вида:

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`name`) VALUES ('NULL')
```

тут получается что NULL идет как текст (строка)

А мне нужно чтобы был таким:

```
INSERT INTO `products` (`name`) VALUES (NULL)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Не подставляйте переменные в текст запроса, а используйте [подготовленные выражения](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) и [привязку](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) тогда любые значения, включая NULL будут садиться правильно. Плюс к этому данный подход защищает вас от возможных SQL-инъекций и взлома сайта через них.

```
$param = NULL;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `products` (`name`) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $param);
$stmt->execute();
```

Обратите внимание, обрамление в кавычки в тексте запроса при этом вообще не требуется. А следовательно переменная $param может принимать любое значение (даже содержащее кавычки) и в коде дополнительно предусматривать разные случаи не требуется.

Answer (score 1):

Так так и вставляйте:

```
INSERT INTO products (name) VALUES (NULL)
```

Или вот так:

```
$param = NULL
INSERT INTO products (name) VALUES ($param)
```

Когда вы ставите `NULL` в `''` - получается строка, в первом примере вы делаете это прям в запросе, во втором - когда объявляете переменную

А можно просто поставить значение по умолчанию, потому что, как я понимаю, поле будет не одно, а несколько. Тогда при запросе просто не заносите `name` и после запроса в базе будет `NULL`

Comment: А как по вашему должен выглядеть код, в случае если переменная может быть текстом (тогда нужны кавычки), а может быть NULL (и тогда они не нужны). Писать кучу IF что бы подставлять кавычки, когда надо ? А вообще подстановка переменных прямо в текст запроса очень плохой тон, ибо данных подход ответственен за 60% всех взломанных сайтов в мире

Comment: @mike как по мне это вообще странный способ занесения, второй вариант с использованием значения по умолчанию - правильный и следует использовать его, потому что: нет данных - нет уязвимостей

Comment: А где сказано, что значение по умолчанию у данной колонки это NULL ?

Comment: @mike у меня в ответе написано, что нужно поставить значение по умолчанию и это решит проблему.

Comment: И как тогда итоговый код должен выглядеть ? собирать текст запроса по кусочкам, анализируя какая переменная null, а какая нет. Это конечно вариант, только чего то совсем универсального может не выйти, потому что одним переменным нужны будут кавычки, другим нет, а в третьих вообще внутри значений есть кавычки и их экранировать надо. И главное, зачем вообще применять сложный, потенциально опасный и глючный код, когда есть нормальные решения, поддерживаемые на уровне драйверов БД